# Getting 503 on various files

Tags: themes, errors, child-theme

I'm having issues with BeTheme, to say the least.

I can't figure out why loading a page, either on the front end or back end, always gives me TONS of 503 errors for the various javascript, css, or image files, especially when I can open those individual files in separate tabs using their urls and have no problem.

This occurs even when I've disabled all plugins. It's just something about BeTheme that's driving me crazy. Has anybody experienced this issue or know how I could go about troubleshooting it?

(sorry, I can't release the url for the website, as it's for a political campaign and needs to stay private until it's finished. If there are any questions about the set up, I'll be glad to answer.)

```
HOST: DreamHost Dedicated Server
DOMAIN REGISTRAR: GoDaddy
DNS NAME SERVER HOST: DreamHost
THEME: BeTheme 12.3
WORDPRESS VERSION: 4.5
```

Comment: Also, these errors are only showing up in Chrome.

Comment: Is there anything in the web server error logs? (if you can get those from GoDaddy) I'd guess the theme is server-side resource hungry and [you're getting 503s from resource limits](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/website-errors-503-service-temporarily-unavailable-5089). I assume you've tried one of the default themes and aren't hitting this? I suggest you contact GoDaddy support to find out why your requests are failing / which limit you're hitting, and if it is the theme being too resource-hungry then either try profiling it yourself (e.g. xdebug) or ask the theme developer for the help.

Comment: Well, it would probably be DreamHost I'd get in touch with since they're the web host and GoDaddy is just the registrar, but I get what you're saying. And yea, the Twenty Sixteen theme doesn't have the same issue. But here's the weird thing... I don't get any of the 503 errors when viewing the site in Safari, but they're everywhere in Chrome.

Comment: Oops, yes, sorry for misreading that. I'd guess Safari is making fewer simultaneous connections to your site then, but I can't see a way to configure that in Chrome to try dropping the number. It looks like it's more easily configurable in Firefox - you could try that and vary the number of connections? But beyond that I'm not sure what to suggest sorry other than checking the host error logs.

Comment: I don't consider this an answer because I don't know what happened exactly, but I'm not seeing the 503 errors in Chrome any more. It might be because I changed the DNS Name Servers from CloudFlare to DreamHost, so maybe the CloudFlare caching isn't messing things up anymore, and maybe the DNS just needed some time to update. Not sure.